# Why socket.io makes server's CPU 100%? Nuxt+koaJS

Tags: node.js, vue.js, socket.io, nuxt.js, koa

I have problem with SocketIO + NuxtJS. 
In Production Mode, sometimes server's CPU Usage is suddenly 100% since I attatch socketIO server. Please help me if you know about this problem. thx..

Maybe I guess this problem is related to disconnect event "Transport Polling". I debugged socket io server logs, last log's lines of all were `user disconnected: H2X9WQSD6DSzMFT-AAEO, polling`.

**My Backend Code**

```
// server.js
…
const http = require('http')
const app = new Koa()
const socket = require('Socket.IO')
… 
const server = http.createServer(app.callback())
const io = socket(server)
…
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected’)
    socket.on('message', message => {
        io.sockets.emit('message', message)
    })
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('user disconnected: ' + socket.id + ', ' + socket.handshake.query.transport)
    })
})
server.listen(port)
…
```

**My FrontEnd Code**

```
// plugin/socket.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import io from 'Socket.IO-client'
Vue.prototype.$socket = io(process.env.HOST_URL)

// nuxt.config.js
...
plugins: [
 { src: '~/plugins/socket.js', ssr: false },
 ],
...

// pages/test.vue
...
export default {
 data() {
    return { messages: [], message: '' }
 },
 mounted() {
    this.$socket.on('message', message => {
        this.messages.push(message)
    })
 },
 beforeDestroy() {
    this.$socket.off('message')
 },
 methods: {
    //chat to server 
    handleChat() {
        if (this.message) {
            this.$socket.emit('message', this.message)
            this.message = ''
        }
    },
 }
}
```

[CPU 100% Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUHTl.png)